# Pandas wrongfuly converting date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with some columns with the format D-M-Y, as in:

23/05/2020

stored as objects. Now, I want to substract two columns to obtain differences in days. For that i do:

```
df["date1"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], format="%d/%M/%Y").dt.date
```

and the same for other column (i only want dates, not time). The problem is, pandas doesnt seem to recognize this because for example

```
   date 1     date 2
25/05/2020  23/05/2020  
20/07/2020  20/07/2020  
05/05/2020  03/05/2020  
25/05/2020  25/05/2020  
13/05/2020  12/05/2020
```

are converted into:

```
2020-01-25  2020-01-23  
2020-01-20  2020-01-20  
2020-01-05  2020-01-03  
2020-01-25  2020-01-25  
2020-01-13  2020-01-12
```

Which clearly gets every sybstraction wrong. So, I have seen some others questions but doesnt adress this problem. Original data is in csv format, and I use encoding= latin1 when reading from csv because of the accents, but i dont think that is the problem.
I have tried some other tricks, but i cant think far beyond to_datetime. Really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the format to

```
pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Since `%M` here is minute